# Need some help to create XUnit for my code

Tags: c#, xunit

I need to write a XUnit Test for my C# code with Visual Studio 2022. I had everything framed up but problem when i created my first or "test" XUnit Project with the solution, it throws me that my namespace "AutoReleaseConfigSheet" from my main code is not available. Any advise will be much appreciated.

My Directory Structure:

```
    C:.
    │   .gitlab-ci.yml
    │   App.config
    │   AutoReleaseConfigShee.csproj.user
    │   AutoReleaseConfigSheet_v1.c.sln
    │   cdav.cs
    │   cdav.csproj
    │   cdav.csproj.user
    │   Configure.ini
    │   debug.log
    │   Oracle.DataAccess.Common.Configuration.Section.xsd
    │   Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.Configuration.Section.xsd
    │   packages.config
    │   readthis.txt
    │
    ├───bin
    ├───GPUCache
    ├───obj
    ├───packages
    └───Properties
```

**Part of my MAIN code:**

```
        using IniParser;
        using IniParser.Model;
        using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
        using System;
        using System.Data;
        using System.IO;
        using System.Net.Mail;
        using System.Data.SQLite;
        using ClosedXML.Excel;
        using Serilog;
        using Serilog.Events;

        namespace AutoReleaseConfigSheet
        {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main()
                {
                    ConfigureLogger();

                    try
                    {
                        Log.Information("Application started");
                        string configIniPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Configure.ini");
                        Configuration config = LoadConfiguration(configIniPath);

                        InitializeFiles(config);

                        ProcessInputFile(config);

                        TriggerEmailNotification(config);

                        SendReport(config.MailRecipients, config.MailServer, config.MailTitle);

                        Log.Information("CDAV Executed successfully");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Log.Error(ex, "An error occurred");
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        Log.CloseAndFlush();
                    }
                }

                static void ConfigureLogger()
                {
                    string logDirectory = "log";
                    string logFile = Path.Combine(logDirectory, ".log");

                    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .MinimumLevel.Information()
                        .WriteTo.Console(restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information)
                        .WriteTo.File(logFile, rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day, restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information)
                        .CreateLogger();
                }

                static Configuration LoadConfiguration(string configIniPath)
                {
                    var parser = new FileIniDataParser();
                    IniData data = parser.ReadFile(configIniPath);

                    Configuration config = new Configuration
                    {
                        MiasConnStr = GetConfigData(data, "DBConnector", "MiasConnStr"),
                        OrderFromOFSFileDirectory = GetConfigData(data, "MasterFiles", "OrderFromOFSFileDirectory"),
                        MailTitle = GetConfigData(data, "EmailDistro", "Mail Title"),
                        MailServer = GetConfigData(data, "EmailDistro", "Mail Server"),
                        MailRecipients = GetConfigData(data, "EmailDistro", "Mail Recipients"),
                        ReportRecipients = GetConfigData(data, "EmailDistro", "Report Recipients"),
                        ReportTitle = GetConfigData(data, "EmailDistro", "Report Title")
                    };

                    return config;
                }

                public class Configuration
                {
                    public string MiasConnStr { get; set; }
                    public string OrderFromOFSFileDirectory { get; set; }
                    public string AutoMailODMPath { get; set; }
                    public string EmailBodyPath { get; set; }
                    public string RlsOdrTxtPath { get; set; }
                    public string HlOdrTxtPath { get; set; }
                    public string MailTitle { get; set; }
                    public string MailServer { get; set; }
                    public string MailRecipients { get; set; }
                    public string ReportRecipients { get; set; }
                    public string ReportTitle { get; set; }
                }
            }
        }
```

**Part of my XUnit Test Code:**

```
using Xunit;
using AutoReleaseConfigSheet;

namespace AutoReleaseConfigSheet.Tests
        {
            public class ProgramTests
            {
                [Fact]
                public void LoadConfiguration_ValidData_ReturnsConfiguration()
                {
                    // Arrange
                    string configIniPath = "path_to_test_config.ini"; // Update this with the actual test config file path
                    Configuration expectedConfig = new Configuration
                    {
                        MiasConnStr = "TestConnStr",
                        OrderFromOFSFileDirectory = "TestOrderDirectory",
                        // ... initialize other properties with expected values
                    };

                    // Act
                    Configuration actualConfig = Program.LoadConfiguration(configIniPath);

                    // Assert
                    Assert.Equal(expectedConfig.MiasConnStr, actualConfig.MiasConnStr);
                    Assert.Equal(expectedConfig.OrderFromOFSFileDirectory, actualConfig.OrderFromOFSFileDirectory);
                    // ... assert other properties
                }

                // Add more test methods for other parts of your code
            }
        }
```

I did moved the public Configuration class to same level as Program, but still it does not resolve the situation.

Comment: You have to specify the access modifier if you don't your `Program`-class to be private. Same for its class methods.

Comment: I have tried to update my 'Program'-class to "public" same does other methods or classes within 'AutoReleaseConfigSheet'. I used command console to add 'AutoReleaseConfigSheet' as reference to my XUnit test.cs and it throws me below error. That could be the issue...

'''

Comment: Post the error.